# Meaning of index of a multiplication symbol in a Cartesian product

Tags: category-theory, notation, products, pullback

I've just started to read about Category Theory.

More precisely [nLab, opposite category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opposite+category). I'm trying to understand the expression:
$$
\circ_{C^{op}}
  : 
  C_{\mathrm{mor}}^{op} {}_{s^{op}}\times_{t^{op}} C_{\mathrm{mor}}^{op}
  =
  C_{\mathrm{mor}} {}_{t} \times_{s} C_{\mathrm{mor}}
  \stackrel{\simeq}{\to}
  C_{\mathrm{mor}} {}_{s} \times_{t} C_{\mathrm{mor}}
  \stackrel{\circ}{\to}
  C_{\mathrm{mor}}
  \,,
$$

Are the indices of $\times$ something that can be explained within the set theoretical Cartesian product or it is something strictly connected to Category Theory (it seems to occur near the word *pullback*)? In the first case I would appreciate a short explanation, in the second case I'll wait to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, these indices are used to denote a pullback rather than a (cartesian) product. In a general category, given two arrows with the same codomain $X\stackrel{f}\longrightarrow Z\stackrel{g}\longleftarrow Y$, their pullback is an object, denoted $X\ {_f\times_g }\ Y$ (or more frequently, $X\times_Z Y$), and equipped with two maps $\pi_1 :X\ {_f\times_g }\ Y\to X$ and $\pi_2:X\ {_f\times_g }\ Y\to Y$ such that $f\circ\pi_1=g\circ\pi_2$, wich is universal among such objects; this means that for every object $W$ and arrows $u:W\to X$ and $v:W\to Y$ such that $f\circ u=g\circ v$, there exist a unique map $w:W\to X\ {_f\times_g }\ Y$ such that $\pi_1 \circ w=u$ and $\pi_2\circ w=v$.

By contrast, the product of $X$ and $Y$ is defined by the same data of an object with two maps, but without the condition $f\circ\pi_1=g\circ\pi_2$, and it has the same property, but without the conditions $f\circ u=g\circ v$; so the pullback is a bit like a product but with an additional restriction. Incidentally, the pullback is often called "fibered product".

In the set-theoretical case, the pullback can be easily obtained from the product: whereas the product is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, the pullbacks is the set of such pairs with the additional condition that $f(x)=g(y)$. The two maps $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are then just the restriction of the product projections to this set (i.e. $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\pi_2(x,y)=y$).

In this specific case, the pullback $C_{\mathrm{mor}}\ {_{s} \times_{t}}\ C_{\mathrm{mor}}$ is the set of pairs of arrows $(\alpha,\beta)$ such that the source/domain of $\alpha$ is the target/codomain of $\beta$; in other words, it is the set of pairs of arrows that can be composed in your category $C$.